# Sub controller to update values from Main controller on change in values

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service, angularjs-controller

I have the following structure -

- ABC.html
- processingModalwindow.html
- mainController.js
- mainService.js

ABC.html uses mainController.js
In the mainController.js, I shall have the logic to display a $modal when ABC.html is displayed. This modal dialog wll be an GET request to another html processingModalwindow.html

NOW, in the modal dialog, I need to update some numbers for processing as per another AJAX call being triggered from mainController into mainService.js

How can I update the ajax response from MainController to the modalwindow after each ajax response. I believe I should create another subController in the mainController.js, but then how should I push the values on to the modal HTML?

Some research and I found that I could use services to achieve this, but not sure how to get around in this case. What would be the best approach?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Services are singletons that are accessible app-wide, so any changes you make to a service would be visible in any other angular component that the service is injected into within the same app.

Therefore simply inject the mainService into your modal's controller.